# Can I improve MigraDoc v1.32 table generation time?

Tags: pdf-generation, migradoc

I've been working with MigraDoc v1.32 for on a project and have been running into very slow PDF generation times when building tables. I looked on the MigraDoc FAQs and saw that they had addressed the slowness of generating tables with their v1.5 Beta release, but not all functionality from 1.32 had been implemented yet. I tried upgrading to 1.5 through NuGet but found that some of the features that I was using (Unit, TextMeasurement, among others) weren't done yet.

I'm wondering if anyone has had any success either getting MigraDoc 1.5 working properly, or has found some way to speed up the table generation time in 1.32?

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.50 beta 3 works very well and stable.

If you find that details are missing, use the Issue Submission Template to let the makers of MigraDoc know what's wrong.
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=832

Or try 1.32 with the Pakeha patch:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1601#p1601

In my tests 1.50 was faster than the patched 1.32. I would go for 1.50.

**Update:** The TextMeasurement class was removed from MigraDoc for good.
An updated version of the TextMeasurement class for use with PDFsharp 1.50 can be found in the forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9390#p9390
Just include the TextMeasurement.cs file in your project.